# Unable to install avm

Tags: windows, installation, anchor

I am using instructions from this site to install Anchor on my Windows laptop
https://book.anchor-lang.com/getting_started/installation.html#anchor

I have executed the command `avm install latest` and it gave this error:

`Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)`

And the next command `avm use latest` returns this error:

`Version 0.25.0 is not installed, no current version. Error: You need to run 'avm install 0.25.0' to install it before using it.`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the install command like this: `cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.26.0 anchor-cli --locked`

I'm not 100% sure why this works, however, I was running into the same exact problem. If you specify the version via the `--tag` flag (***v0.26.0 would be where you replace with the version you're interested in***) and change the command from `avm` to `anchor-cli` it seems to work.